# Add or Update an entity without knowing if its exists

Tags: entity-framework

I have a group of entities that I don't know if they already exists in the Database.
If they exists - I need to update them, if they does not exists - I need to add them (for each entity it might be one or the other, and there are 10000 of them...)

(scenario - I'm importing data from a file, if I import the same file - nothing should happen, if the file is changed - I need to update).

Can I achieve it with Entity Framework without having to search for each entity before I add it ?

(if I want to add - I need to use AddObject, if I want to modify - I need to use attach and ChangeObjectState).

is there a way to avoid the search - than do one of the 2 options ?

(looking for "Add or Update" way....)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In EF you must know if you want to insert or update the entity => if you don't know it you must first search the database. You can reduce the complexity by not using EF and use SQL directly but you will still have to search for the entity before you decide to insert or update. In case of direct SQL this whole can be done in the single database roundtrip (SQL Server 2008 offers special command `MERGE` this) whereas EF needs separate roundtrip for search and separate roundtrip for update or insert.

Edit: Another solution with better performance would be to fetch all data to database by some quick way - for example temporary table filled by stored procedure with table valued parameter or with bulk insert. Once you have all records in some processing table you can use SQL to update all records existing in real table and insert all not existing records.

Comment: It might be a good solution to hold all the data but I will have to restructures my app for that. as I have many calls for update/add and I don't want to load everything each call. I'll also look for @tdykstra solution, I don't have this from my ObjectContext, and I'm not sure how to move to DBContext and what it means. will have more info tomorrow .

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the DbContext API (EF 4.3 and EF 5), you can use the AddOrUpdate method. You get sample code showing usage of this method when you enable Migrations, or you can see an example in this older blog post from the EF team:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-beta-1-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Will look into it. I'll report back tomorrow.

Comment: But this solution does exactly what @Dani doesn't want to do. Every call to `AddOrUpdate` internally executes query to check if the entity exists in the database. Moreover it uses some additional reflection so it is the slowest solution among all and [it should be used only in Migrations](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/). Btw. it is also not designed for concurrent application because in delay between call to `AddOrUpdate` and `SaveChanges` other thread / application can add that entity.